# Como obtener porcentaje con decimales SQL managment 2018

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente estructura de tabla:

[image: Tabla]

De la cual quiero cambiar todos los valores por su porcentaje correspondiente por lo cual tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT id,  (c*100)/sum(c+e+na) AS 'C',
            (e*100)/sum(c+e+na) AS 'E',
            (na*100)/sum(c+e+na) AS 'NA',
            (sum(c+e+na)*100) / sum(c+e+na) AS 'porcentaje'
from prueba
group by id, c,e,na
```

Y tengo el problema de que al parecer me redondea todos los valores ya que la suma de todos las columnas dan 99 y una 98... les muestro el resultado de la consulta:

[image: ResultadoConsulta]

Entonces, me gustaria pedirles su ayuda para saber como obtener los valores con decimales ya que en la tabla anterior la fila del id 2 en la columna 'na' deberia ser 10 y no 9 o bien obtener los valores como 0.38, 0.52, 0.10, gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más fácil para corregir la consulta es agregar un punto decimal a tu constante y que se conviertan implicitamente el resto de los valores para evitar la división de enteros.

```
SELECT id,  ( c * 100.)  / SUM( c + e + na) AS 'C',
            ( e * 100.)  / SUM( c + e + na) AS 'E',
            ( na * 100.) / SUM( c + e + na) AS 'NA',
            ( SUM(c+e+na)*100.) / SUM( c + e + na) AS 'porcentaje' --Esto siempre será 100
FROM prueba
GROUP BY id, c, e, na --Creo que esto es incorrecto y no te agrupará las filas como esperas.
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar cualquiera de estas funciones

```
SELECT CAST(12 AS DECIMAL(7,2) ) AS result;
// Result = 12.00

SELECT CAST(campo AS DECIMAL(7,2) ) AS result;
// Result = campo con 2 decimales

SELECT CONVERT(decimal(4,2), campo) AS result;
// Result = campo con 2 decimales
```

Answer (score 1):

Las columnas están en formato int debes computar el porcentaje en decimal con un cast o un convert

```
SELECT id,  (c*100)/sum(c+e+na) AS 'C',
            (e*100)/sum(c+e+na) AS 'E',
            (na*100)/sum(c+e+na) AS 'NA',
            cast((sum(c+e+na)*100) as decimal(7,2)) / cast(sum(c+e+na) as decimal(7,2)) AS 'porcentaje'
from prueba
group by id, c,e,na
```